# set array element and its index to a label

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tableview

Hi I have an array of elements

```
var prices = ["100", "200", "90", "", "", "300", "100"]
```

And method cellForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellid") as? PriceViewCell
        for (index, item) in prices.enumerated() {
                    cell?.priceLbl.text = "Item \(index): \(item)"
                }
        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }
```

The output is this:

[image]

However preferred result is this(marked red):

[image]

Comment: Well you are assigning all values from the iteration to the same cell. Do you want all values in the same cell because then you need to join them together instead of overwriting them as you do now?

Comment: You don't say so, but the fact that your code assigns the result of your for loop to cell?.priceLbl.text suggests that you are trying to populate a table view or collection view.

You need to provide more context for your question.

Comment: @DuncanC I`ve added some code and screenshots. Please have a look

Comment: You should use `indexPath` to access the array instead of a for loop since cellForRowAt will be called for each row. Something like `cell?.priceLbl.text = "Item \(indexPath.row + 1): \(prices[indexPath.row])"`

Comment: cell?.priceLbl.text = "Item \(indexPath.row + 1): " + prices[indexPath.row]

Answer (score 1):

I am putting [Joakim Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson)'s answer into a question so future users can find it easier:

```
cell?.priceLbl.text = "Item \(indexPath.row + 1): \(prices[indexPath.row])"
```